# Undefined Class Error in Smarty using PHPStorm 10

Tags: smarty

I have mac, installed PHPstorm 10, now trying to install smarty, similar to as mentioned in following tutorial , http://phpwebscript.blogspot.com/2009/09/smarty-installation-steps-on-wamp-and.html,

i have installed mamp supporting PHP  5.6. everthing is configured file. as mentioned in the tutorial i have edited php.ini file under correct version. After everything is setup i get error on following;

```
     require ('/Applications/MAMP/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');

     $smarty =new Smarty() //Undefined class smarty error;
```

When i run,

```
     echo (defined('SMARTY_DIR') ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

i get yes

any fix please.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, following were the problems that i fixed,

1. Include path was not set, i though i have included path in php.ini now its ok, but when you create a project in phpstorm or netbeans, there is a folder created external libraries or include path, you have to include smarty, I did it and now everything ok
2. i had copied testinsall from net which was causing error, retyped it and now smarty is running perfect on phpstorm 10.